# Image saved to "LocalFolder" not picked by Notification Toast?

Tags: c#, windows, windows-8

I have saved (Write) an image to "LocalFolder" not being picked up by the notification Toast.

```
StorageFolder systemLocalFolder = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
string path = systemLocalFolder.Path + "\\" + R.GetResourceString("CachedImageFolder") +
                                "\\" + R.GetResourceString("CachedImagePrefix") + contact + ".png";
path = path.Replace(@"\", @"/");
path = @"file:///" + path;
image.SetAttribute("src", path);
binding.AppendChild(image);
```

After setting this image , the toast does not show up.

However doing this:

```
image.SetAttribute("@Assets/Logo.png", path);
```

Does show up the toast with the image.

But i want to write a file and then use it and not pick from App Package.

Win8+XAML+C#

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [file:/// protocol isn't supported for Windows 8 Store apps](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br230844.aspx) BUT you don't need it anyway.  Something like this should get you there:

```
path = @"ms-appdata:///local/" + R.GetResourceString("CachedImageFolder") + "/" 
            + R.GetResourceString("CachedImagePrefix") + contact + ".png";
```